# When Do Not Disturb is set on iPhone, what will fire off and what will not?

Tags: iphone, ios, calendar, alarm, alert

It seems if Do Not Disturb is set to on (manually or daily scheduled) on the iPhone, then alarm (in the Clock app) will still fire off, but Calendar alerts will not fire off?

What are the rules?

Answer (score 5):

[Source](http://www.macworld.com/article/3034720/ios/how-to-master-do-not-disturb-on-ios.html).

## Mastering DND

> Do Not Disturb effectively silences almost all notifications while you aren’t actively using your phone. You can set it so your phone **won’t** ring or buzz when you receive phone calls, new text messages, new email, or new invitations from annoying “friends” who want to challenge you to a game of Candy Crush or whatever.
>
> Certain notifications **get through no matter what**, such as *timers* and *alarms* set through the Clock app. You may still receive various government alerts too, such as *emergency alerts* and *AMBER alerts*.

Continue to the source article for more detailed info on customizing DND to get the most from the feature.

Comment: There are 2 ways that I set a reminder for myself: Clock app alarms or Calendar event alerts.  Is there a way to allow Calendar events alerts show up? Otherwise, it is like sometimes some of my reminders could work, sometimes they won't. I need to set the Do Not Disturb on because I get too many calls for somebody pretending to be the IRS, pretending they are the Microsoft Tech dept trying "fix" a virus on my computer, and asking for money sponsor for police events, or asking for whether I need to remodel the kitchen

Comment: You can do some level of customization.  Go to the source link in my answer and it will show you how to do it.

Comment: I searched for the word "calendar" on that page and nothing showed up. Searching for "alert" and only government alert and AMBER alert showed up

Comment: You can customize DND to prevent calls from people not in your contact list.  That will help with the unwanted calls you've received.  I'm not sure about Reminders or Calendar events, I don't think they had that in mind when creating it because most people use DND when sleeping.

Comment: so I think you are saying I can only black list all the apps that I don't want for disturbance, but cannot white list only 2 things that are allowed to notify me: Clock Alarm and Calendar Alerts